# Unity2D multiple sprite problem (sprite editor problem)

Tags: unity-game-engine, sprite

I wanted to make simple tile map. I imported it to unity and make it multiple sprite. Then I wanted to slice it in Sprite Editor but I got this error...

I was trying to download the sprite window editor from Package Manager but I couldn't find it.

The inspector of sprite that I added

[image]

The Error that I got after click Sprite Editor

[image]

Could you help me?
Thanks!

Comment: Do you have the 2D Sprite package installed via the package manager?

Comment: I don't know how to check it

Comment: Ok I didn't have it installed, I couldn't find the package manager thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Open **Package Manager** window from top bar by selecting **Window > Package Manager**.

[image]

Then select **2D Sprite** from the list and press **Install**.

[image]